# How to scrap Google review ratings, specifically on how to identify which HTML tags or classes to specify when scraping from google?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and have been trying to get the review ratings of '4.1 star' from the google review in the picture below but cant seem to get it

[Google webpage review, trying to scrap that 4.1 star rating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctTIZ.png)

My code looks like this:

```
import re
import json
import urllib.request
import datetime as dt
import pandas   as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
import requests
import unicodedata 
from bs4            import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
#from inscriptis     import get_text
from lxml           import html

file                = open("../input data/Hameediyah.txt", "r",encoding="utf8") #Downloaded an offline version for this test

contents            = file.read()
b_soup              = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
p_restaurant_list_tag = b_soup.find_all('a')

ratings = b_soup.select('div.wDYxhc > div.Ob2kfd > div > span.Aq14fc')  #Got stuck here as there is no output whatsoever.
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: i think with div ids and classes like these are autogenerated, it would be better if you maybe tried using the xpath without the classes i.e something like this "/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[35]/div[2]/h3/a'

Comment: @Kapil how to i determine the order of div? like the way you ordered it in div[3]/div[2] etc.. seeing as there are so many div breakdown

Comment: browsers like firefox/chrome/edge usually have the inspect element, where you can select an element and copy its xpath, you need to see if theres any additional options under copy xpath, and see which would be more appropriate

Comment: @Kapil Thanks,  i got the full xpath, but unfortunately the output still shows nothing, thanks for the tip tho

Comment: do you have a url? for this downloaded page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my best guess is that, because websites like google dynamically load their content after initial page load, it would be better to dump the initial response in a file and inspect that

i have tried and it works for multiple places too

```
import requests

from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    'https://www.google.com/search?gs_ssp=eJzj4tZP1zcsSTMpKUwpMGC0UjWoMDYwSUw2tjQ3NrAwTjK1SLIyqEg2sDAzMEkyMzRIMzQzMDfwEs1IzE1NTcmsTMxQKEotLkksLUrMKwEAHHYWgw&q=hameediyah+restaurant&oq=hameediyah&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j46i175i199i512l3j0i512j46i175i199i512j0i512j0i457i512j0i512.3567j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'
    , 'https://www.google.com/search?q=eiffel+tower&sxsrf=ALiCzsaz4zdPAFCW44e04rU8LCS17sqVDQ%3A1658421173814&ei=tX_ZYtSzMdb_z7sPse-EiAo&ved=0ahUKEwiU4s-ntIr5AhXW_3MBHbE3AaEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=eifel+tower&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEcyBAgAEEdKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFgAYNcDaABwAngAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAyAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz'
]
for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    encoding = response.headers['Content-Type'].split('; ')[1].split('=')[-1]
    # for easier readability ((response.headers['Content-Type'].split('; ')[1]).split('='))[-1]

    body_text = bytes.decode(response.content, encoding)

    # not needed for now
    # b_soup = BeautifulSoup(body_text, 'html.parser')

    with open('dump.html', 'w') as dump:
        dump.write(body_text)

    tree = html.fromstring(body_text)

    rating_element = tree.xpath(r'/html/body/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/span[2]/div/span/span[1]')
    rating = rating_element[0].text
    print(rating)
```